# AsciiDoc to html5 external css

Tags: css, html, ascii, asciidoc

I'm trying to convert my AsciiDoc to html5 with the following command :

`asciidoc -b html5 -a icons -a toc2 -a stylesheet=article.css myPost.adoc`

It doesn't find my css file cause it look it wrong place : 
`asciidoc: WARNING: myPost.adoc: line 1: include file not found: /usr/local/Cellar/asciidoc/8.6.9/etc/asciidoc/article.css`

Also ascii put some css in the generated html file so how can I remove it (or pass it to external file) cause I ave multiple file to convert and don't want to duplicate this.

Answer (score 1):

There also is an option `stylesdir=...` for **asciidoc**.

Looking at your error message, I wonder if you put `article.css` into `/usr/local/Cellar/asciidoc/8.6.9/etc/asciidoc`?

Maybe `article.css` is located somewhere else?

If so, call it like this:

`asciidoc -b html5 -a icons -a toc2 -a stylesheet=article.css -a stylesdir=/path/to/article.css myPost.adoc`

---

This is explained in [the asciidoc docs](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/produce-custom-themes-using-asciidoctor-stylesheet-factory/).